# Inserting a string into a list<string> element?

Tags: c#, string, list

I'm using this line of code to insert a value from an array into a certain line, in a list of lines.

```
lineList[LineNumber].Insert(lineList[LineNumber].Count(), pArray[i]);
```

After debugging all the variables are correct, the pArray is passed in as a parameter and lineList is inherited from another class. I can't see why this wouldnt work, all the lines that are added are just empty?

Comment: Ehm, which programming language?

Comment: Sorry ill add a tag, its C#, it asks for a location I think.

Comment: OK. And `linelist` is a list of strings? So that would make `linelist[lineNumber]` a string, right?

Comment: Yeah linelist is a list of strings, I want to add pArray[i] to the line in linelist that is lineList[lineNumber].

Comment: I dont want to make the list longer, I need to make that list element longer by adding pArray[i] if that makes sense. That works in one case Mikey, but I not all, as I dont want each element on a different line, the code above will be executed more than once.

Comment: But what does `lineList[LineNumber].Count()` mean? That is not standard C# for strings.

Comment: @MrLister It's *unexpected*, but it is definitely not non-standard: `Count()` is a LINQ extension method called on the string interpreted as an `IEnumerable<char>` :)

Comment: Ah, OK then. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because .NET strings are immutable; [`string.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) returns a new string, rather than modifying an existing one. If you need to modify the string, add an assignment, like this:

```
lineList[LineNumber] = lineList[LineNumber]
    .Insert(lineList[LineNumber].Count(), pArray[i]);
```

This should be equivalent to

```
lineList[LineNumber] += pArray[i];
```